# AJAX in WP Plugin returns 0 if not login as admin

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

i'm new in wordpress plugin development facing problem for the plugin testing below. The plugin is using shortcode and when click on a search button, jquery will trigger ajax call to admin-ajax.php.

**Problem:**
The get_result will be called if only i login as admin. It will display Match Found or No Match Found. 
If not login, it will return 0

Please help, thanks in advanced

```
function wp_search_scripts() {
    // Your actual AJAX script
    wp_enqueue_script( 'myAjax', plugins_url( 'custom.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ) );
    // This will localize the link for the ajax url to your 'my-script' js file (above). You can retreive it in 'custom.js' with 'myAjax.ajaxurl'
    wp_localize_script( 'myAjax', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_search_scripts' );

function search()
{
  global $wpdb;
  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "searching";
  // will return NULL if there isn't one
  if ( $wpdb->get_var('SHOW TABLES LIKE ' . $table_name) != $table_name )
  {
    $sql = 'CREATE TABLE ' . $table_name . '(id INTEGER(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(1), PRIMARY KEY  (id) )';
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    dbDelta($sql);
    add_option('search_mydatabase_version','1.0');
  }
}register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'search');

function search_now() {  
  $temp = "<input type='text' id='txtsearch' name='txtsearch' style='border:1px solid #000;padding:4px 8px;width:350px;'/>";
  $temp .= "<input type='submit' id='getResult' Value='Search' style='background:#f00;color:#fff;padding:4px 15px;border:none;margin:-10px 10px 0px 10px;'/>";
  $temp .= "<br /><div id='result'></div>";  
  return $temp; 
}add_shortcode("search-now", "search_now");

add_action('wp_ajax_get_result', 'get_result');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_result', 'get_result');




function get_result() {
  $txtVal = $_POST['txtVal'];

   if(!$txtVal)
    {

  $results .= "<h4>Match Found</h4>"; 
}else {
$results .= "<h4>No Match Found</h4>";
}          

}
```

the javascript file

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
    jQuery("#getResult").click(function(){

        var txtVal = jQuery("#txtsearch").val();
        alert(txtVal);

            jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/wordpress4/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
                    data: {
                        action: 'get_result',
                        txtVal: txtVal,
                    },
                    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){                        
                        jQuery("#result").html('');
                        jQuery("#result").append(data);

                    },
                    error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        alert(errorThrown);
                    }
                }); 
    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your get_result function should be like

```
function get_result() {
   if( is_admin() ) { // checks that current user is admin
      $txtVal = $_POST['txtVal'];

      if(!$txtVal) {
         $results = "<h4>Match Found</h4>"; 
      }else {
         $results = "<h4>No Match Found</h4>";
      }          
   } else {
      $results = "not ad admin";
   }
   echo $results;
   die();
}
```

Comment: thanks for response but it doesn't solve the problem. Only login as admin able to see the result.